# asynchronously load Deezer Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, deezer

I'm trying to asynchronously load the Deezer JS SDK following what has been explained here:
http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/init

With an empty page and copying exactly the provided sample, I get an error :

```
Cannot read property 'length' of null dz.js:67
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Object.DZ.Event.resolve (http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js:59:138)
    at Array.<anonymous> (http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js:150:10)
    at Object.DZ.Event.triggerEvent (http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js:62:342)
    at Object.DZ.player.onLoad (http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js:143:10)
    at DZ.onDeezerLoaded (http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js:7:52)
    at DZ.communication.receive (http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js:109:1)
```

Here is the code I use:

```
<div id="dz-root"></div>
<script>
    window.dzAsyncInit = function() {
        DZ.init({
        appId  : 'xxxxx',
        channelUrl : 'http://www.blbablalba.com/channel.php'
        });
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = 'http://cdn-files.deezer.com/js/min/dz.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('dz-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm guessing you might want to change the appID and channelUrl?

Comment: I had changed it to my appId and channelURL of course :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I got the same problem today, and realized that a modification of the value of `document.body.innerHTML` was causing that problem.

=> Removing that line of code solved it! :-)